# How I can create payment document in FlowPay

Tags: authorization

[According to document](https://docs.sandbox-new.flowpay.it/#tag/Fatture/paths/%7E1%7BtenantID%7D%7E1invoices/post) I am testing API using Insomnia. Generating a payment document is a single operation that I have used a single POST call to the intended document endpoint
create, for example:

```
POST https://app.sandbox-new.flowpay.it/api/:tenantID/invoices
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <accessToken>
```

Body:

```json
{
  "attachments": null,
  "currency": "EUR",
  "date": "2022-08-23T17:32:28Z",
  "items": [
    {
      "amount": 123.12,
      "description": "hello",
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ],
  "number": "123465",
  "recipientIban": null,
  "recipientVat": "132412341",
  "senderIban": null,
  "senderVat": "23412341245",
  "terms": [
     {
        "amount": 123.12,
        "description": "hello",
        "expire": "2022-08-25T17:32:28Z",
        "information": "hello",
        "method": null,
        "recurringInfo": null
    }
  ]
}
```

To get `:tenantID` I have followed flowpay [documentation](https://docs.sandbox-new.flowpay.it/#section/TenantID/Premessa)

But I am getting `not authorized to upload this invoice` error message.

```json
{
   "errorDescription": "not authorized to upload this invoice",
   "code": 2003,
   "statusCode": 401,
   "requestID": "1FAF3537-FA0B-4642-AF75-94FE9FDC8E2A",
   "service": 2
}
```

Can anybody help please?